# gdb Err presenting content of array with variable size

Tags: c, arrays

consider the following simple code. I'm trying to assign an array with variable size "size" entered by the usr. the code "behaves" with expected results.

however, if I try to view the value of array in gdb (using eclips) I get [0]. trying to display it as an array (using the expression (*array@size) or even manually right clicking on array in variable window and ask to "display as array" i get an error: "Can't take address of \"array\" which isn't an lvalue."

If i now change the assignment to be with fix size (e.g. int array[6];) everything works OK including proper display in gdb

any ideas?

```
int main(void) {
    int size;
    puts("Enter size of array:\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    int array[size];
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    array[i]=i;
}
```

Comment: Your  code snippet misses a closing brace and any relevant `#include`s.

Comment: Doing `p *array@size` inside gdb (run form the commad line) works for me.

Comment: Thanks alk.  My code  has all relevant #includes and also the closing brace. Digging some more into it, I saw that in the variable length case, the debug error message also says that the value of array was "optimized out" which is strange as I set -O0 flag. I also tried declaring the array with "Volatile" and stil get the optimized out message. Any idea. Forgot to mention I'm running eclips on OS X if it makes any difference